# Fritzbox 7530AX fails to uphold 2,4Ghz WiFi

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wifi-configuration, fritzbox

My new Fritzbox 7530AX for some reason fails to uphold the 2,4Ghz WiFi. At least once (sometimes even twice) a day the connection completely stops working and devices even refuse to connect to the WiFi entirely. Even stranger, sometimes when this happens I get a message that the "WiFi is connected without internet access" and some other times trying to turn on the WiFi freaks out my devices so much they turn off WiFi on their own seconds after failing to establish a connection.

Restarting the deviced does absolutly nothing to fix this issue. The only thing I was able to do to fix it so far is restarting the Fritzbox. But as you can imagine later or the nex day the same issue occurs once again. I did not temper with any settings of the Fritzbox, it did a standard installation on its own the first time I plugged it in. The current OS is up to date, version 07.31.

So far I was able to deduct that only the 2,4Ghz WiFi is affected by this weird behavior. Devices that connect via 5Ghz (like the two laptops in our household) work just fine and even continue working just fine when devices connected via 2,4Ghz stop working. I already tried separating the two networks with different SSID's or even turning off the 5Ghz completely, so all devices have to connect via 2,4Ghz. When only the 2,4Ghz is used, every device was affected from this connectivity problem. Unfortunatly for example the phone or my tv don't seem to be able to use 5Ghz, so I really need to fix this issue with the 2,4Ghz frequency/network.

System diagnosis and whatever else the AVM web interface provides doesn't seem to recognize anything wrong and just tells me everything is working as intended. I don't even know where to tackle this issue anymore. Digging a little deeper into the WiFi diagnostics of windows it says the connection was unable to authenticate. However when looking at the event log in the AVM web interface it says the device connected, but didn't respond in time, so it automatically got disconnected again.

Has anyone ever seen such a weird behavior before? I'd be very thankful for any kind of suggestions on what to do to fix this issue once and forall. Let me know if you need any additional information!

Comment: 2.4GHz is an open band that is used by a lot of devices: WiFI, Bluetooth, wireless headphones, baby phones and so on. If you are living in a house with multiple appartements disturbances on 2.4 GHz band are pretty common.

Comment: @Robert A WiFi analyzer I tried to help figure this out shows literally nothing apart from the fritzbox itself, my network and the guest network I set up. I'll try disabling the guest and see if that helps any. Apart from that, there really are no other sources of interference I think. I don't own wireless speakers, telephones or other things. Currently no bluetooth devices are active for longer than an hour or two when I listen to music on wireless headphones. There are no other networks from neighbours.

Comment: Update the router firmware and see if that helps

Comment: @John As said in my post it already is up to date.

Comment: A Wifi analyzer does, as the name implies" search for Wifis. But as I mentioned a lot of other devices and protocol also use those frequencies. Those devices are not recognized by a Wifi analyzer. You may check the router itself, AFAIR Fritz!OS has a built-in scanner that also can detect non-Wifi disturbances.

Comment: @Robert The built in scanner doesn't recognize any disturbances, only one neighbouring network and half a dozen free channels.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced exactly the same issue as you described with my new 7590AX (FRITZ!OS 7.50).
I believe I have now stabilised my 2.4Ghz network by Adjusting the Wi-Fi channel settings.
Wi-Fi / Wi-Fi Channel: "Adjust Wi-Fi channel settings"
Select an appropriate "Radio Channel" (for me Channel 12 was the least noisy)
"Wi-Fi standard": "Wi-Fi 4" (changed from Wi-Fi 6)
Devices are able to consistently see the 2.4Ghz SSID and are no longer being dropped off that network.
Hope that helps you too.